# Java SMPP client implementation

Tags: java, sms-gateway, smpp

I want to implement a simple client application in java to connect and send messages using an SMS Gateway. The service provider has configured the gateway and I have it's IP, Port, Username & Password. I have downloaded [SMPP](http://smppapi.sourceforge.net/) API.

Question is there is not enough documentation. So is there any good examples or some documentation..?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [good pdf documentation](http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv34_gsmumts_ig_v10.pdf).

This  document  defines  version  3.4  of  the  SMPP  protocol  and  specifies  the  command  and response format to be used when implementing an SMPP v3.4 protocol interface.

It is intended for designers and implementers of an SMPP v3.4 interface between an SMSC and an External Short Message Entity (ESME), as illustrated in Figure 1.1

Comment: Just a very side note: in the future please avoid capital at each word and use punctuation and maybe paragraphs. It will make your answer *a lot* easier to read.